# please help to understand code below

Tags: php, smarty

```
{if $smarty.get.type eq "statistic"}
{assign var="total" value=0}
{assign var="i" value=1}
<form action="" method="post" name="grid_form" id="form">
<input type="hidden" name="show" value="1"/>
    <div class="ip_date" style="text-align: center">
        Begin:<select>
                            <option value="begin_m">January</option>
                        </select> 
                        <select>
                            <option value="begin_y">2008</option>
                        </select> 
        End: <select>
                        <option value="end_m">January</option>
                    </select> 
                    <select>
                        <option value="end_y">2008</option>
                    </select> 
            <button type="submit" class="button">OK</button>
        <!--    <input type="submit" class="button" value="xls" name="xls"/>-->
    </div>
```

What does it mean?:

```
{if $smarty.get.type eq "statistic"}
{assign var="total" value=0}
{assign var="i" value=1}
```

And how should I create a php script to list 5 years that passed from current moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{if $smarty.get.type eq "statistic"}
{assign var="total" value=0}
{assign var="i" value=1}
```

this means in php is

```
if($smarty->get->type == 'statistic')
{
    $total = 0;
    $i = 1;
    ---
    ---your code
}
```

php script for five years

```
$curYear = date('Y');//gives you current year
$startYear = curYear -5;
$yearArr = array();
for($startYear; $startYear <= $curYear ; $startYear++)
{
    $yearArr[] = $startYear;
}
```

for $yearArr array you can make your list.

Comment: thank you for help.
I mean, how should I create a script, that will show me on <select> list of years, like 2016 - 4 years, and then we get: 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016.

Comment: if you got it please mark my answer and close the question @sheia